# How can I redeploy my ico/erc20 token from Rinkeby to the main Ethereum network?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, ico, rinkeby

If you know and have a tutorial please attach the link in this thread.

My token on Rinkeby looks like this:

https://dappuniversity.github.io/dapp_token/

Comment: Just to make sure I didn't misunderstand: you can't move your token between networks. You have redeploy it in the other network and the tokens in different networks have no connection to each other.

Comment: yes correct. how i redeploy in public network. i use this command in geth: geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi="personal,eth,network,web3,net" --ipcpath "~/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc"

Comment: i'm new in blockchain and cryptocurrency .sorry

Comment: Please don’t do that... it will cost u about 0,2 ether at least, which is a big amount of money... if u are new then take your time explore the test networks and how to connect to different networks.. and how to use truffle , ganache , remix id, infura... it is not very complex but need time and test networks are here for that without wearying money

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just change the network you are connecting to when deploying the contract, to use the main network instead of Rinkeby.

However, running  a successful ICO is very complex and I would not recommend doing this unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: @Mahdi The --rinkeby flag is what's connecting you to Rinkeby instead of the main chain.

Comment: i use this command for deploy on rinkeby network:
geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi="personal,eth,network,web3,net" --ipcpath "~/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc"

Comment: @MahdiRahmani  yes it is this flag, but I doubt you can sync the main network locally . it is very big and need a super PC . There is something called infura , you can use it to connect to the main network